# White Space in HTML from Django Template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a django app that I need to get in a list format. My problem is the how the event list is stylized in HTML after I filter my results. I have tried to add `&nbsp;` and it does not seem to take and probably isn't the best practice.

I have been successful with using a table, but really don't like the look of it. Is there a way to just have an unordered list with appropriate spacing using a div or span tag? For example I would like for my list to look like

```
2/6/2013     Widget Company        Chicago
2/7/2013     Dodad Company2        Kansas City
```

rather than

```
2/6/2013 Widget Company Chicago
2/7/2013  Dodad Company2 Kansas City
```

Here is my code, currently as a table.

```
 {% if latest_events %}
     {% for event in latest_events %}
<table border="1">

     <tr>
       <td>  {{ event.event_date }}  </td> <td>{{ event.company  }}</td> <td> {{ event.venue  }} </td> <td>{{ event.city  }}</td>
     </tr>

     </table> 
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No Events are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This *is* tabular data, it belongs in a table.  Don't choose an inappropriate (or avoid the appropriate) tag just because you "don't like the look of it".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are dealing here with HTML only, I recommend using Twitter Bootstrap since it comes with a lot of nice things(style/css) you can use and is really extremely easy to use. For example, it has tables, give it a look at it [Twitter Boostrap tables](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables) or maybe the grid [Twitter Bootstrap Grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

Comment: I really like this framework. Is there a way to override the text alignment in the table?

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap is not a framework and you can use it with Django, it would just give you some style to your templates/HTML

Comment: Bootstrap
Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.

Comment: I ended up using this "framework". I think it will save me a ton of time instead of trying to make my own CSS. I solved the width of cells problem with html by adding width for each cell like this: <td width="20%"> {{ event.venue  }}

Answer (score 0):

Use the [center](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#center) template-tag - it will do the job for you.

Available alternatives: [ljust](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ljust) and [rjust](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#rjust)

Comment: Padding an element with spaces won't do anything in HTML because all whitespace is condensed down to a single space by default.  In other words, 100 spaces is the same as a single space.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is extra spacing between the elements, add some padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/n762q/

```
table.associates td, table.associates th {
    padding-right: 2em;
}

<table class="associates">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2/6/2013</td>
            <td>Widget Company</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2/7/2013</td>
            <td>Dodad Company2</td>
            <td>Kansas City</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternately, you could specify a `min-width` on your cells or the table itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/n762q/1/

```
table.associates {
    min-width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is browsers strip sequences of white space, so(_ = space) `____` will become `_`.
As stated above the solution is to style your table.

Just setting a width on the table element may give you the results you're looking for as tables do not consume more width than necessary by default. However they adjust their cells with the change of their width.